# Angular 11: IIS UrlRewrite to deep-link in Angular app not working

Tags: angular, url-rewriting

I have a legacy WebForms application, and want to replace a part (a route of it) by an Angular app, but the route shall stay the same, and more routes will follow in the future. So I want to deep link into the  Angular App.

So, for the showcase, I have a virtual directory named "app" under the "Default Web Site" in IIS.
The app directory points to the folder C:\Playground\AngularApp\dist, where the built Angular app is located.

I have this web.config in root of Default Web Site:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <!-- disable inheritance for the system.webserver section -->
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>       
        <rules>
         <clear />      
         <rule name="Rewrite static files" stopProcessing="false" enabled="true">
              <match url="^products\/([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="app/{R:1}" />
        </rule>     
        <rule name="Rewrite App" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="^products" />                  
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app/" />
        </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
        </handlers> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The /products route is currently handled by Asp.Net Routing, so there is no such folder or virtual directory at the Default Web Site.

The Angular App uses the base ref

```
<base href="/products/">
```

and the following web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <clear />  
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>        
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The Angular app routing implements two urls:

- \cars
- \bikes

So, when I enter localhost/products I see the content of the cars page in the Angular app, but Angular's routing defaults to url localhost/products/cars in browser.

**Problem:**
How can I achieve, that the url localhost/products rewrites correctly to localhost/app/cars, but address in browser should stay localhost/products ?

When I try adapting the rewrite rules to go into "app/cars" instead, then I get the 404.0 error page from IIS, stating the requested resource is not available:

- Requested URL:      https://localhost:443/app/cars/
- Physical Path:      C:\Playground\AngularApp\dist\cars\

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trying, I assume, what  I wanted to achieve is not possible by design.
A working solution now is:

- In DefaultWebSite I rewrite 'products' to 'app'
- Inside the 'app' I directly show content at the root route level, but I can't use subroute 'cars' or 'bikes'

Another working solution is:

- In DefaultWebSite I rewrite 'products' and everything below to 'app'
- Inside the 'app' I define two routes 'cars' and 'bikes', and default route goes to 'cars'
- so url in the browser will become 'products/cars' or 'products/bikes'

Another working solution is:

- In DefaultWebSite I rewrite 'products/cars' and everything below to a virtual application in IIS named 'app-cars', hosting a standalone app only for cars.
- In DefaultWebSite I rewrite 'products/bikes' and everything below to a virtual application in IIS named 'app-bikes', hosting a standalone app only for bikes